# "bitcoinrpc.authproxy.JSONRPCException: -342: non-JSON HTTP response with '401 Unauthorized' from server"

Tags: bitcoin-core

I used the following code to connect to the bitcoin core client and encountered this error:

```
bitcoinrpc.authproxy.JSONRPCException: -342: non-JSON HTTP response with '401 Unauthorized' from server
```

My configuration file: bitcoin.conf is written as follows:

## Expose the RPC/JSON API

```
server=1
rpcbind="127.0.0.1"
rpcport=8332
rpcuser="bitcoin"
rpcpassword="J9JkYnPiXWqgRzg3vAA"
```

May I ask what caused my code to report an error, and how should I solve this problem?

Comment: This error can depend also from the library/method that you are using to talk with the RPC interface

Comment: Why do you wrap stuff on quotes needlessly?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can be wrong.  More details are required, like the code you mentioned.

There is a more thorough discussion on this matter here:

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/106601/113203